# compilation error: class, interface or enum expected

Tags: java

I get the error above during compilation.

The first place where it occurs is code:

```
public void clear(int i, int j) {
    this.model[i][j]=0;
}
```

The code which it's inside is just a normal class with a constructor but without `main()`. This instance method is called from another `.java` file.

What am I doing wrong? Am I compiling something I shouldn't compile as a first file or something else?

Comment: I think you should post the whole class.

Comment: You will need to post the whole class. I suspect you are missing an opening or closing brace somewhere.

Comment: Post class declaration, probably you missed the `class` keyword

Comment: Ok, thx. Guys. I'll do it then :-) (didn't want to bother with it before). Here it is :-) :

Comment: It's a sudoku solver:

Comment: Tried to copypaste it, it says it's too long. Please stand by, I'll modify it

Comment: Ok, thx guys. It was a missing bracket issue :-) . I solved it when trying to reduce the code. Now I have another issue: "missing return statement, but I guess, it should be as another question. Thanks a lot. How do I "like" responces here on forum? Thanks

Comment: Btw. should I delete it if I solved it myself (thus it might be irrelevant for other folks) or should I let it stay? Thanks for the advice

Comment: Thanks Michael! (I don't know how to rank answers here yet) It was a bracket of course

Answer (score -3):

My guess is you have a parantheses issue. You need the class/interface declaration. Make sure you start your class like:

```
public class Dog {
private int[][]model;

 public Dog(){
  //do nothing
 }

 public void clear(int i, int j) {
    this.model[i][j]=0;
  }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't post answers that are unsubstantiated guesses. Ask for clarification in the comments (you won't be able to do this until you have 50 reputation), then post an answer once you have enough information.

Comment: There's [a badge it it for you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) if you delete this before the community does. I wear mine with pride.